# What model to classify a discretized continuous variable

Tags: classification, discrete-data, continuous-data

Consider a variable $y$ (typically, $y_i$ is something like *number of inhabitants of city $i$*) and some given features $X$. Let us assume that these features are continuous (eg. total city area, number of shops, roads). We want to use features $X$ to explain $y$.

Although the variable $y$ should naturally be seen as a continuous one, it has been discretized in my training set to five classes: $0 \leq y < 300$, then $300 \leq y < 1.000$, and so on. Thus, even for my training set, I do not know the continuous value of $y$, only its discrete class $C(y)$.

I need to use this training data to predict $C(y)$ for the other cities (ie. cities that are not part of my training set). Please note that I only wish to predict to which discrete class each other city belongs (I am not seeking for an accurate prediction of $y$ itself).

I am wandering what could be a theoretically satisfying approach to this kind of problem. Should I handle this as a classification problem even though there is an underlying hidden continuous variable? Can I identify borderline data points and give them less weight? Should I convert $C(y)$ to a continuous variable using the middle of the class as an estimate?

**I would appreciate any idea or reference on this topic. Thanks to all.**